# React, typescript - 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-29k6xp?file=index.tsx)

It's a basic React app using typescript.

I have one component which is a Navbar which just shows some links in a simple div.

In this demo the Navbar is shown on the page but on my actual app it doesn't show and I get an error in the console

`Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 
  'IntrinsicAttributes'.  TS2559`

You can see this when you hover over the Navbar in the demo with the red squiggly line line underneath.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it.

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. [Here's how to do a React MRE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child component doesn't expect any children.

Simply switch from:

```
<Navbar>

</Navbar>
```

to:

```
<Navbar />
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows error because you pass empty line as child and `Navbar` component doesn't expect any.
Try:

```
<Navbar />
```